# Does the Ghostwise Halfling Silent Speech allow two-way communication?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, halfling, telepathy

The description of the ghostwise halfling's Silent Speech trait (SCAG, p. 110) says:

> You can speak telepathically to any creature within 30 feet of you. The creature understands you only if the two of you share a language. You can speak telepathically in this way to one creature at a time.

If I am understanding that correctly as written, it only allows the Halfling to speak *to* the target (not *with*) and does not allow for a telepathic reply. Is that correct?

If that is the case, it is definitely different than similar things like the Message or Telepathy spells...

Answer (score 12):

### Correct, it doesn't specify it allows two-way communication.

Other items in the game, like [Telepathic Bond](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Telepathic%20Bond#content) states the targets can communicate. With this spell stating "targets" it implies that both creatures affected can communicate to the other. Since the Ghostwise Halfling does not specify this then it would not have two-way communication.

Answer (score 9):

## No, it doesn't - just one-way.

The [ghostwise halfling](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/halfling#GhostwiseHalfling)'s Silent Speech trait (SCAG, p. 110) says:

> You can speak telepathically to any creature within 30 feet of you. The creature understands you only if the two of you share a language. You can speak telepathically in this way to one creature at a time.

The use of "speak to" rather than "speak/communicate with" seems to suggest that the telepathy is one way. Furthermore, the trait doesn't describe any way for the creature to respond, and the subsequent sentences seem to reinforce this interpretation.

[Rules designer Jeremy Crawford confirms this ruling in an unofficial tweet from September 2016](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/775468842914942976):

> Twitter user: *Please, for the love of the Gods.. Can people speak back telepathically to a Ghost Wise Halfling using racial telepathy?*
>
> Crawford: **The Silent Speech of the ghostwise halfling lets you telepathically talk to someone. It doesn't enable replies.**

(He also clarifies in response to another user that the ability can be used by a druid in Wild Shape.)