# Can your familiar (via Find Familiar) initiate telepathic communication with you?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, familiars, telepathy

The *[find familiar](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/find-familiar)* spell says (emphasis mine):

> While your familiar is within 100 feet of you, ***you* can communicate *with it* telepathically**.

So, clearly you can speak to it telepathically, say to issue commands to it. But can it:

- Reply to your message?
- Initiate a conversation with you?

---

As it happens, I'm going to have a [pseudodragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/pseudodragon) familiar (via warlock, [Pact of the Chain](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#PactBoon-389)), which can respond in it's own way:

> ***Limited Telepathy.*** The pseudodragon can magically communicate simple ideas, emotions, and images telepathically with any creature within 100 feet of it that can understand a language.

So in my case, it's more about whether it can reply with words (either because it can speak to me telepathically due to *find familiar*, or because I've "initiated" a telepathic conversation with it, similar to the *[message](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/message)* cantrip, even though that's not actually telepathy), or whether it can only reply *at all* because of its own ability (via "***Limited Telepathy***", which obviously won't be with words, if it turns out that the telepathy via *find familiar* is one-way only).

I'm hoping to figure out which interpretation is correct by knowing the answer to my above questions about whether any familiar (via *find familiar*) can telepathically communicate with the caster at all.

Comment: Possibly related, an answer here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154839/does-the-kenku-racial-curse-prevent-the-awakened-mind-class-feature-and-similar

Comment: Not really all that related, as that one is specific to the Awakened Mind feature of GOO warlocks, whereas I'm referring to the telepathy inherent in the _find familiar_ spell (in other words, the first half of my post could equally apply to wizards). That said, it is a good example of the sort of one-way telepathy that I'm wary of, hence why question (since _find familiar's_ telepathy doesn't specify either way).

Comment: The one-way thing is why I considered it "possibly related".  Worth looking at, anyway.

Comment: Yeah, like I say, a good example of the sort of one-way thing I'm wary of. Thanks!

Comment: Related questions: "[Can a wizard's familiar wake the wizard using its telepathic link?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/128960)" and "[Is Dominate Person's telepathic link one-way or two-way?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/113554)" and "[Does the Ghostwise Halfling Silent Speech allow two-way communication?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110446)" and "[Is the Warlock's Awakened Mind telepathy two-way, or only one-way?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/51575)" and "[Can a "find steed"-sourced mount actually talk to you \(telepathically\)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/117254)"

Comment: @Medix2 I agree with the duplicate you found; that is basically the same question I'm asking. In that case, it'll be up to my DM, but I've always got the pseudodragon's "Limited Telepathy" to fall back on...